# unresponsive right click result box overlays everything

Tags: 14.04, screen, click-policy

Every now and then my system runs into following issue

When I right click on an item to select one of the options, the resultant box becomes unresponsive and just stays there, it overlays everything in the system, all apps, desktop everything. Box is not transparent because of which, I can not see the data it is overlaying.

Often it occurs in gedit and I have to close all my files and re-open just to get rid of the unresponsive box. But when it happens with other things like files explorer, I have to restart the system, shutting all my work down.

It is really disturbing my work, does anyone know what is the cause of this issue and how I can fix it, without having to restart system or apps.

System Info:

- Dell Inspiron15 3000 series
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Memory: 7.7 GiB
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4
- Graphics: Intel® Broadwell
- OS type: 64-bit
- Disk: 972.9 GB

Info about graphic driver:

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:66 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

I have also attached a screen shot [image]

Comment: One possible cause is that there is too much stuff running causing the system to become heavy and become unresponsive. But I do not usually run heavy programs, mostly I have multiple browser tabs, shell terminals and a lot of text files. I do not think just this many programs should make system unresponsive, I think my system has good memory etc...

Comment: Are you running the Intel video driver from the repositories or have you tried upgrading it with the [official installer](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads)?

Comment: Looks like it is driver issue, not OS issue... How did you upgrade your graphic driver?

Comment: I did not upgrade graphic/video driver. My system was setup by office IT long ago, so possibly it has whatever the default configurations are supposed to be.  I'm editing the question to include driver related info

Answer (score 0):

There should be messages in your /var/log/Xorg.0.log file.

Obviously you can't get to them when the system is hung so run a terminal , click the title bar and set it to allways on top. then in the terminal run

```
tail -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

This will ensure you can see any log messages that might relate to the issue, if you can post it here we can solve it for you.

Another good source of info to run in a sticky window lack the last one is

```
journalctl -f
```

it contains more general log messages that might also explain it

Comment: have you applied all available updates for this system ?